# Drywall Corner Order (inside/outside)

Tags: drywall, mudding

I have a section of drywall coming together around a doorway where an abutting wall joins with under 1.5" clearance.

I am not installing casing on the doorway but am installing corner bead on the entryway.

I am wondering whether I should install the tape on the inside corner or the bead on the outside corner first. Also can I trim paper faced corner bead to fit this narrow wall?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can trim your corner bead paper. If you are going to do so, I would run your corner bead first and then tape over the top to help hold it all together.

If you aren't trimming the corner bead paper then I would reverse it and tape your inside corner first and then install your corner bead.

Alternatively, if you cased that doorway and trimmed it out you could avoid all of that.